# DateTime Compare doesnt work PHP

Tags: php

So i want make some date compare which do something if true
and I already try to echo $end , $data['end'] and $data['start] and they have exactly the same value in my database, but why does my php go to false which echo 'cant';

```html
<?php if($member->isReady2($gmdate)){

//do something
}
else
{
echo 'cant';
}


//other page

public function isReady2($end){
   $data = $this->_db->getTime('tbdeadline');
   $data2 = $this->_db->getTime2('tbdeadline');
   
   if($end < $data['end'] && $end > $data2['start']){
    
    
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
    
   }
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: What are the values of `$gmdate`, `$data` and `$data2`? I bet they are strings that represent dates in a country-specific format.

Comment: $data =2017-12-30 00:00:00, $data2=2017-12-04 00:00:00  gmdate are current date 12/15/2017 12:49:16

Comment: If they are strings then they are compared as strings, of course. How do you expect the interpreter to guess that you consider them as being dates? Use [`DateTime`](http://ro1.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects to simplify your work with dates and times.

Comment: ah... isee, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Like @axiac said, you would need to compare like objects. You could use strtotime to convert everything to a Unix timestamp for comparison:

```
$gmdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if(isReady2($gmdate)){
  echo"Success";
}
else
{
  echo 'cant';
}

function isReady2($end){
      $end = strtotime($end);
      $data  = strtotime("2017-12-30 00:00:00");
      $data2 = strtotime("2017-12-04 00:00:00");
            if($end < $data && $end > $data2) {
                return true;
            }
      else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```